# Redirect logs from file to Systemd journal

Tags: systemd, logs, systemd-journald, systemd-unit

I have a program which is started by systemd service `myprogram.service`. Problem is that it is writing its logs directly to the log file `/opt/myprogram/logs.txt`. I want to redirect its logs into systemd journal, so I will be able to read them with `journalctl`.

Is it possible to amend `myprogram.service` to tell Systemd to pipeline text from specific file into its journal?

Comment: Is the application able to instead write its output to stdout? Some applications do that when run with a `--no-daemon` (or similar) flag.

Comment: Or a `--syslog` switch.

Comment: @Wieland Problem with that particular application is that it is hardcoded to write logs into file. That is why I'm trying to pipeline it.

Answer (score 0):

As a start, I would try a combination of `tail` and `logger`.

```
tail -f /opt/myprogram/logs.txt | logger
```

`tail` will continuously read all new lines from the file and duplicate them in stdout. And logger will take those lines and send them to system log.

EDIT:

Since the piping is doing buffering there is a chance that the logger will sleep for some time (until the default buffer of 4Kb fills out). That can be remedied by disabling buffering with `stdbuf` or `unbuffer`:

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 tail -f /opt/myprogram/logs.txt | logger
```

Comment: I have tried to add `ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c 'tail -F /opt/myprogram/data/log.txt | systemd-cat'` to systemd service. It works but as `tail` should be left running when I'm trying to start service it is fail with timeout, because systemd waits for `tail` to exit.

Comment: Disable pipe bufering.
Add `unbuffer` or `stdbuf -i0 -o0` to the `tail`.
For example: `stdbuf -i0 -o0 tail -f ...`

Comment: It fails with the same error `# systemctl start myprogram
Job for myprogram.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.`. Systemd waits until `tail` returns exit code so buffering shouldn't help with it.

Comment: I think you are mixing something. The suggested tail+logger solution works for sure in the user mode. If you starting it from systemd.service.... it could be a cause of the error. Not sure how exactly, but 'systemctl' in the error message points in that direction.

Try running tail+logger from a script which starts your application, of if the app itself is running by systemd - just add a log copy script to startup (or just run it manually).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no way to change the output filename in the app, maybe you could forced create `/opt/myprogram/logs.txt` as a symlink to `/dev/stdout` in the service unit, either as a prestart or poststart step or both?

- This could also be to `/dev/stderr` depending on your needs.